# Help show the following isomorphism cannot exist.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working on problem 8 part B of [this released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F02_Final_Exam-K.Kedlaya.pdf).

> Given $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x + 2$ and $g(x) = x^3 + 2x + 1$, show that there is no isomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle \to \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle g(x) \rangle$ such that $\phi(x + \langle f(x) \rangle) = x + \langle g(x) \rangle$.

It provides a hint to evaluate $f$ at $x + \langle g(x) \rangle$. After reducing as much as I could I got (if I did the arithmetic correctly, and if I interpreted "evaluate" correctly):

$$\langle g(x) \rangle^3 + \langle g(x) \rangle^2 - \langle g(x) \rangle x + \langle g(x) \rangle + x^3 + x^2 + x + 2$$

Which interestingly enough, eventually becomes:

$$\langle g(x) \rangle^3 + \langle g(x) \rangle^2 - \langle g(x) \rangle x + \langle g(x) \rangle + f(x)$$

So:

$$f(x + \langle g(x) \rangle) = \langle g(x) \rangle^3 + \langle g(x) \rangle^2 - \langle g(x) \rangle x + \langle g(x) \rangle + f(x)$$

$$f(x + \langle g(x) \rangle) - f(x) = \langle g(x) \rangle^3 + \langle g(x) \rangle^2 - \langle g(x) \rangle x + \langle g(x) \rangle$$

But what does it mean? Does it mean anything? Any further guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The polynomial ring is $\mathbb Z_3[x]$ in the test you linked to.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: I still applied simplifications as if it was $\mathbb{Z}_3$ if that is what you are wondering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x+\langle f(x)\rangle$ and $v=x+\langle g(x)\rangle$, so we know that
$$
u^3+u^2+u+2=0,\qquad
v^3+2v+2=0
$$
If an isomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi(u)=v$ exists, then we also know that
$$
v^3+v^2+v+2=0
$$
so
$$
2v+2=v^2+v+2
$$
and
$$
v^2-v=0
$$
In other words
$$
x^2-x\in\langle g(x)\rangle
$$
Since $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain, this is impossible.

---

Note that we don't really use the complete information: no ring homomorphism with the stated property exists.

Comment: Ok, so I think I get it, I made a small typo in my question, but was able to follow through and get $v^2 - v + 1 = 0$. But still, $x^2 - x + 1 \not\in \langle g(x) \rangle$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to denote $x+\langle g(x)\rangle$ with $[x]$. Then $f([x])=[f(x)]=[x^3+x^3+x+1]=[x^3+x^2+x+1-(x^3+2x+2)]=[x^2-x-1]\ne [0]$. That $[x^2-x-1] \ne [0]$ is because every class of polynomials mod $g(x)$ has a unique representative of degree less than the degree of $g$ by division.

Then such an isomorphism would give a contradiction, since if $\varphi$ were such an isomorphism then $[0]=\varphi([0])=\varphi(f([x]))=f([x])\ne [0]$, where the $[x]$ in the argument of $\varphi$ is the class of $x$ modulo $f(x)$.